# Erro na captura de informação em arquivos com uso da função fseek()... Qual o problema?

Tags: c, while

Eu estou com problemas numa função de captura de infos de um arquivo com a função fseek() [não sei se existe uma alternativa melhor...]. 
Voltando ao problema, eu quero ler um arquivo que possui:

" 2165327575 R"
" 7625621 W" e assim por diante...

E armazenar esse numero numa var int e a letra num char e mandá-las para tratamento em outra função.

Mas estou fazendo algo errado, mas não sei o que é!

O código:

```
VETOR_CACHE TrataCache(VETOR_CACHE cache, CACHEDESC descricao, int *access_count, int *read_hits, int *read_misses, int *write_hits, int *write_misses)
{
    int endereco, i=0;
    char endereco_aux[100];
    char op,ch;
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen("input.dat", "r");
    if(arq == NULL)
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    else
    {
         printf("Entrou aqui 1\n");
        while( (ch=fgetc(arq))!= EOF )
        {
            fseek(arq,1,SEEK_SET);
             printf("Entrou aqui 2\n");
            while( (ch=fgetc(arq))!= 'R' ||  (ch=fgetc(arq))!= 'W' || (ch=fgetc(arq))!= '\n')
            {
                 printf("Entrou aqui while\n");
                endereco_aux[i] = ch;
                //printf("%s\n", endereco_aux);
                i++;
            }
             printf("Saiu while\n"); //Não saiu ainda...
            i=0;
            fseek(arq, 0,SEEK_CUR); //aqui ta errado eu acho
            if((ch=fgetc(arq))== 'R' ||  (ch=fgetc(arq))== 'W') //aqui ta errado ... quero percorrer e gravar os W/R 
            op = ch;    
            if( (ch=fgetc(arq))!= EOF )
            {
                endereco = atoi(endereco_aux);

                //A IDEIA É CHEGAR AQUI COM O OP E O ENDERECO E MANDAR PRA OUTRA FUNÇÃO TRATAR...
                printf("%d\n", endereco);
                printf("%s\n", op);
                *access_count = ContaLinhas();
                cache = OperaCache(true , endereco, op, cache, descricao, read_hits, read_misses, write_hits, write_misses);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return cache;
}
```

Eu usei esses 'printf()' para me basear onde o erro ocorria na execução...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seu problema é mais com a função `fgetc` do que com a `fseek`. Toda vez que você chama `fgetc`, você lê um caractere e posiciona o file pointer no próximo caracter.

 No while que testa se o char é igual a 'R', 'W' ou '\n', você chama `fgets` e joga o resultado em `ch`, então quando você sai desse while `ch` contém 'R', 'W' ou '\n', que é o caracter em que você está interessado. No `if` mais à frente você chama `fgets` de novo, e acaba perdendo esse caracter, pois ele pega o próximo. Me parece mais fácil comparar o `ch` que você já tem com '\n', dessa forma: `if (ch != '\n')`. Assim você garante que `ch` ou é 'R' ou é 'W', e pode armazenar na variável `op`.

 Outro comentário é a respeito de `fseek(arq, 0,SEEK_CUR);`. Essa função posiciona o file pointer exatamente onde ele está atualmente, então pra mim não faz sentido chamá-la.

 Qualquer coisa posta um comentário aqui. Keep coding

Comment: Sim, eu busquei outra alternativa e achei um ´fscanf´ padronizado que funcionou... Era o que tu disse mesmo, valeu.